# Как принудительно заполнить поле с primary key?

Tags: mysql, orm

Использую фреймворк Kohana. Для организации связей между таблицами, в модели ORM для таблицы указал кастомный primary_key - follower, вместо id. И теперь, при добавлении строки, хоть я и явно указываю, какое значение нужно ввести в поле follower, всё равно добавляется 0. Я чего-то не понимаю, да?

Comment: Значит, поле НЕ определено как первичный ключ - иначе бы не проходила вставка с дублирующимся значением.

Comment: @Akina в самой базе данных - не определено. В модели ORM я определяю: protected $_primary_key = 'follower', чтобы осуществить связь с другой таблицей. Если убираю эту строку - всё нормально записывается в бд. Если вставляю - записывается 0.